# Disable Java deserialization completely

Tags: java, serialization

Is there a way to completely disable java deserialization?

Java deserialization as in `java.io.ObjectInputStream` potentially opens an application to security issues by deserializing so-called serialization gadgets.

I do not use java serialization intentionally, but it is hard to make sure no library that is trusted with some outside input will never perform deserialization. For this reason I would love some kind of kill switch to disable serialization completely.

This is different from caching issues - I want to make sure no object is ever deserialized in my application, including through libraries.

Comment: you can overwrite the private `serialization`-methods to just throw an error. That way the programm dies before any serialization can happend and then you can take action

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable serialization cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673096/disable-serialization-cache)

Comment: You can patch this class to replace it.  In particular you can take out the portions which can be unsafe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to prevent deserialization is to define an agressive deserialization filter (introduced in Java 9 via JEP 290).

For example with `java -Djdk.serialFilter=maxbytes=0 MyApp`, any deserialization attempt (byte stream size > 0 byte) will throw an `java.io.InvalidClassException: filter status: REJECTED` exception.

Or you could use `maxrefs=0`, or simply exclude all classes using a wildcard, i.e. `java -Djdk.serialFilter=!* MyApp` or `java -Djdk.serialFilter='!*' MyApp` on Unix where the "!" needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Java agent to do that. Try [this](https://github.com/kantega/notsoserial) one. Also, a nice read is [this](https://tersesystems.com/blog/2015/11/08/closing-the-open-door-of-java-object-serialization/) blog post discussing more on the topic of disabling deserialization.